# How to dynamically bind Json data to ACE Editor

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui, ace-editor

I've created an AngularJS based application that embeds Ace editor via [UI.Ace directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace) for Json. The app will create a set of editors based on dynamic Json data, i.e. each editor has ng-model that contains Json object. Here is the model:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ui-ace="aceOptions" ng-model="item" style="height: 200px"></div>
</div>
```

However, Ace editor requires stringified Json data and throws following error:

> "Error: ui-ace cannot use an object or an array as a model

On the other hand if I stringify data first then how I can figure out with ng-repeat? So, how one can solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

**Example:**

```
[
    {                           // goes to editor one
        "id": "14",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {                           // goes to editor two
        "id": "45",
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {                           // goes to editor three
        "id": "98",
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "White"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear exactly what problem it is you're experiencing but I was able to put together a demo that appears to do what you're looking for:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in aceModel">
  <div ui-ace="aceOption" ng-model="item"></div>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.aceModel = [];
$scope.aceModel[0] = ';; Scheme code in here.\n' + ...
$scope.aceModel[1] = ';; Different code here for the new editor.\n' + ...
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1KlmqopkmbhvKuMy4he2?p=preview

**EDIT**

I've updated the Plunk with your json and push it onto `$scope.aceModel`

```
  var jsonData = [{ // goes to editor one
    "id": "14",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }, { // goes to editor two
    "id": "45",
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }, { // goes to editor three
    "id": "98",
    "firstName": "Jack",
    "lastName": "White"
  }];

  $scope.aceModel = [];

  angular.forEach(jsonData, function(value, key) {
    $scope.aceModel.push(JSON.stringify(value, null, 4));
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1KlmqopkmbhvKuMy4he2?p=preview

Comment: @K Scandret, thanks for response. The idea is that my Json comes in form of array, i.e. a set of json data which will be iterated in separate editors with ng-repeat. And the problem is one can not bind Json to editor (Ace Library), because its accepts stringified Json and not object or array as it shown in error.

Comment: Updated plunker with your json data. Is this what you mean?